# Angular 2 Multiple layout routing

Tags: angular, layout, angular-routing

On my angular 2 app, I have a completely **different layout between my home page and the rest of the app.**
The rest of the app have only a nav in common.

My url looks like :

http://localhost:4200/       <== this is my home page

http://localhost:4200/cgu    <== a page with nav in common

http://localhost:4200/abc    <== a page with nav in common

**Can someone explain to me the best way to do this ?**

I tried to reproduce this solution :

[How to switch layouts in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38780436/how-to-switch-layouts-in-angular2/38783451#38783451)

But it doesn't work, or I made mistake to adapt it to my case.

**EDIT:**

Finally I tried your solution 
So I created the navigation.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class NavigationService {
  isHomePage: boolean;
}
```

In my home.component.ts

```
@Component({
  styleUrls: ['home.css'],
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
})
export class HomeComponent {

  constructor(private navigationService: NavigationService) {
    navigationService.isHomePage = true;
  }
}
```

In my app.component.ts I try to get the isHomePage value:

```
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(private navigationService : NavigationService) {

    console.log("HELLO");
    console.log(navigationService.isHomePage);
    if(navigationService.isHomePage)
      console.log("HOME");
}}
```

navigationService.isHomePage is `undefined`

What's my mistake ?

Comment: Have you added your service to your `providers` in your mail module? And how come your `HomeComponent` has no selector in the Component declaration? (example: ` selector: 'app-home'`)

Comment: This one could help you. It's working without problems if you only use components. https://stackoverflow.com/a/40508804/1365061

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend reading the [official documentation](https://angular.io/guide/router#!#basics-base-href) as it is very concise and uses examples.

> The Angular Router enables navigation from one view to the next as users perform application tasks.

You would bind a component to a route so that when a user navigates to it it shows the right template.

In order to have a shared navigation, you must place it outside of your `router-outlet`, therefore the content of your views will be contained in said outlet but not the navigation.

__

If you do not want to display it in your homepage you may do the following:

Create a `NavigationService` that contains a boolean `isHomepage`, set it to false once you leave the home page, and true once you navigate to it. Inject it in your navigation component, and in your template:

```
<nav *ngIf="!_navigationService.isHomePage"></nav>
```

This way it will only be displayed out of the home page.

Comment: Yes but this navigation zone must not be printed on my home page

Comment: I have edited my answer, let me know if this helps you out.

Comment: Yes I tought about this solution but I don't think it's the best way to do ?

Comment: I can't really answer that question as I have been using this method in my previous project and it has been working quite well. Have you implemented it?

Comment: Please let me know if my answer has helped, if so do not hesitate to accept it or to ask for more help.