# Best method to set different layout for different pages in angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-template, angular-router

I am new to angular 4. What I'm trying to achieve is to set different layout headers and footers for different pages in my app. I have three different cases:

1. Login, register page (no header, no footer)

routes: ['login','register']

2. Marketing site page (this is the root path and it has a header and footer, mostly these sections come before login)

routes : ['','about','contact']

3. App logged in pages (I have a different header and footer in this section for all the app pages but this header and footer is different from the marketing site header and footer)

routes : ['dashboard','profile']

I run the app temporarily by adding a header and footer to my router component html.

Please advise me a better approach.

This is my code:

### app\app.routing.ts

```
   const appRoutes: Routes = [
        { path: '', component: HomeComponent},
        { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent},
        { path: 'contact', component: ContactComponent},
        { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
        { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
        { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
        { path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent },


        // otherwise redirect to home
        { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
    ];

    export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

### app.component.html

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

### app/home/home.component.html

```
<site-header></site-header>
<div class="container">
    <p>Here goes my home html</p>
</div>
<site-footer></site-footer>
```

### app/about/about.component.html

```
<site-header></site-header>
<div class="container">
    <p>Here goes my about html</p>
</div>
<site-footer></site-footer>
```

### app/login/login.component.html

```
<div class="login-container">
    <p>Here goes my login html</p>
</div>
```

### app/dashboard/dashboard.component.html

```
<app-header></app-header>
<div class="container">
    <p>Here goes my dashboard html</p>
</div>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40508557/multiple-layout-for-different-pages-in-angular-2) on stack-overflow but i didn't get a clear picture from that answer

Comment: This link has couple of ways to do this : https://blog.angularindepth.com/angular-routing-reusing-common-layout-for-pages-from-different-modules-440a23f86b57

Answer (score 175, accepted):

You can solve your problem using child routes.

See working demo at https://angular-multi-layout-example.stackblitz.io/ or edit at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-multi-layout-example

Set your route like below

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    
    // Site routes goes here 
    { 
        path: '', 
        component: SiteLayoutComponent,
        children: [
          { path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
          { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent }
        ]
    },
    
    // App routes goes here
    { 
        path: '',
        component: AppLayoutComponent, 
        children: [
          { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
          { path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent }
        ]
    },

    // no layout routes
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
    { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
    // otherwise redirect to home
    { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

Comment: Demo helped really a lot, i had a little hard time to understand this, mainly i could not get what empty path: '' means, that if there was path: 'admin' generated links would match admin/profile, but since its empty it matches main url links like '/profile' and if child path is also path: '' it matches home page ''. Also was not much clear what exactli are those component: components, that i just have to leave <router-outlet></router-outlet> in original one and post all content in newly generated components. But big tnx :)

Comment: how to make this work when modules are loaded lazily??

Comment: @KarthikHande This will work fine even on lazy loading. (all of my works are on lazy loading). ill try and make a demo suing module loading but can't promise an ETA on this. ping here if you are still having a hard time implementing this on lazy loading modules

Comment: As being new to angular, @RameezRami I'm having confusion regarding, how will the browser to know which routes to go, when both of the above layout starts with  path: ' '  blank route. Even though Its working perfectly, but can you explain a bit please

Comment: @AhsanAlii In simple terms, forget about how the browser handles this. All the route paths are resolved by angular. `{path: '',}` doesn't mean the path ends there, it can have child routes. but if you use `{path: '',pathMatch: 'full',}` it means the scope of your route level ends there. Try to play with the stack-bits demo I have shared and do some experiments by moving `pathMatch` to diffrent levels of route definition.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the comments, they were really helpful to me. However I got a follow-up question: In my layout I'd like to have a button that calls a different function "on click" depending on the page that has been loaded. Is such dynamic content possible with this approach?

Answer (score 10):

you can use child e.g.

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: MainComponent,
        children:{
            { path: 'home'  component:HomeComponent},
            { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent},
            { path: 'contact', component: ContactComponent},
               ..others that share the same footer and header...

        }
    },
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
    { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
    { path: 'admin', component:AdminComponent, 
         children{
            { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
            { path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent }
               ..others that share the same footer and header...
         }
    }
    { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];
```

MainComponent and AdminComponent like

```
<app-header-main></app-header-main>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer-main></app-footer-main>
```

the post talk about separate in diferent files the routes

Comment: as per the answer the url will be 'admin/dashboard', 'admin/profile', i don't want this to happen.. i want to set urls as 'dashboard', 'profile'. is there any way for that?

Comment: I want to say that if you have two differents footer you can, make a footer using a @input to and *ngIf to show one or another view, or make two footers. Anyway it's only an example. You can put as "children" of path: '',component:MainComponent, your DashboardComponent, and profile and forget the path:admin

Comment: its helpfull if you are wotking with admin routes. Thanks for give me the idea.

Comment: how to override content for app-header-main and app-footer-main?

Answer (score 3):

There are cases where the layout and shared elements don't really match the routing structure, or some elements have to be hidden/shown depending on a per-route basis. For such cases I can think of the following strategies (let's take an example of `app-header-main` component - but it will apply to any shared page element obviously):

#### Inputs & css classes

You can provide inputs or css classes to control the inner appearance of your shared elements, such as:

1. `<app-header-main [showUserTools]="false"></app-header-main>`

or

2. `<app-header-main class="no-user-tools"></app-header-main>` and then use :host(.no-user-tools) to show/hide what needs to be

or

3. at a route level (child or not):

   ```
   {
     path: 'home',
     component: HomeComponent,
     data: {
       header: {showUserTools: true},
     },
   },
   ```

And access it through `ActivatedRoute` like so: `this.route.data.header.showUserTools`

#### TemplateRef input

Inside `app-header-main` component:

`@Input() rightSide: TemplateRef<any>;`

Input of type `TemplateRef<any>` where you could feed an `ng-template` element directly

```
<app-header-main [rightSide]="rightside"></app-header-main>
<ng-template #rightside>your content here</ng-template>
```

#### Named slot transclusion

You can author the app-header-main so that it uses named slot transclusion

Inside of app-header-main template:

`<ng-content select="[rightSide]"><ng-content>`

Usage:

```
<app-header-main class="no-user-tools">
  <div rightSide>your content here</div>
</app-header-main>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the problem using ng-content + ViewChild injection of layout into each page component that uses that specific layout.

Using the router for this common use case always seemed like a workaround to me. What you want is similar to Layouts in Asp.Net MVC or MasterPages in WebForm etc.

After struggling with this I ended up with something like this:

see working demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yrul9f

**shared.component-layout.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'shared-component-layout',
  template: `
  <div *ngIf="!hideLayoutHeader" style="font-size: 2rem;margin-bottom: 10px;">
    Layout title: {{layoutHeader}}
    <ng-content select=".layout-header">    
    </ng-content>
  </div>
  <ng-content select=".layout-body">
  </ng-content>
  `
})
export class SharedComponentLayout {
  layoutHeader: string;
  hideLayoutHeader: boolean;
}
```

**page.component-base.ts**

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { SharedComponentLayout } from './shared.component-layout';

export abstract class PageComponentBase {
    @ViewChild('layout') protected layout: SharedComponentLayout;
}
```

**login.component.ts - without header**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { PageComponentBase } from './page.component-base';

@Component({
  selector: 'login-component',
  template: `
  <shared-component-layout #layout>
    <div class="layout-body">
      LOGIN BODY
    </div>
  </shared-component-layout>
  `
})
export class LoginComponent extends PageComponentBase {

  ngOnInit() {
    this.layout.hideLayoutHeader = true;    
  }
}
```

**home.component.ts - with header**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { PageComponentBase } from './page.component-base';

@Component({
  selector: 'home-component',
  template: `
  <shared-component-layout #layout>
    <div class="layout-body">
      HOME BODY
    </div>
  </shared-component-layout>
  `
})
export class HomeComponent extends PageComponentBase {

  ngOnInit() {    
    this.layout.layoutHeader = 'Home component header';
  }
}
```