# no layout in login page in angular 4 project

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing

I am working on angular 4 project I want to create login page in which I don't want the layout that is given for other pages.I don't want the header, footer and sidebar in it. I have seen on stack overflow but I didn't understood it [Best method to set different layout for different pages in angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46527826/best-method-to-set-different-layout-for-different-pages-in-angular-4)

how can i do that any help my code on git hub is https://github.com/s2pedutech/imsui1

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I want login page which don't have the sidebar, header and footer

Comment: If you follow the top voted answer to above question, you should get an understanding to how to do this, https://stackoverflow.com/a/46531192/1074727 , there is also a link to demo where login page has no layout (in that answer)