# One infinite redirect loop in an Angular application

Tags: angular

I'm doing an Angular application with the following routing:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: LoginLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'login',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },
      {
        path: 'login',
        component: LoginComponent
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeLayoutComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuardService],
    children: [
      {
        path: 'users',
        component: UsersComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'detail/:id',
        component: UserComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'dashboard',
        component: DashboardComponent,
        data: {
          expectedRole: 'admin'
        }
      },
      {
        path: 'home',
        loadChildren: './views/home/home.module#HomeModule',
        data: {
          preload: true,
          delay: false
        }
      },
      {
        path: 'error',
        component: ErrorComponent
      },
    ]
  },
];
```

If I'm not logged in and I request any secured url, like for example `http://localhost:4200/users` or `http://localhost:4200/dashboard` then there is a redirect to the `http://localhost:4200/` and the application goes into an infinite loop. If I'm logged in then it works fine.

The browser console displays the following message `Navigation triggered outside Angular zone`.

Here is my `auth guard` service:

```
  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
    const expectedRole = route.data.expectedRole ? route.data.expectedRole : null;
    const tokenPayload = this.tokenService.getDecodedAccessToken();
    return this.authService.isAuthenticated()
    .pipe(
      map(isAuth => {
        if (!isAuth) {
          this.router.navigate(['login']);
          return false;
        } else {
          return true;
        }
      }),
      catchError((error, caught) => {
        return of(false);
      })
    );
  }

  canLoad(): Observable<boolean> {
    if (this.authService.isAuthenticated()) {
      return of(true);
    } else {
      return of(false);
    }
  }
```

I'm on `Angular 7`

EDIT: The issue is now resolved with the following auth guard:

```
  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.authService.isAuthenticated()
    .pipe(
      map(isAuthenticated => {
        if (!isAuthenticated) {
          this.authService.setPostLoginRedirectUrl(state.url);
          this.router.navigate(['login']);
          return false;
        } else {
          return true;
        }
      }),
      catchError((error, caught) => {
        return of(false);
      })
    );
  }
```

and the following routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: LoginLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'login',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },
      {
        path: 'login',
        component: LoginComponent
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeLayoutComponent,
    canActivateChild: [AuthGuardService],
    children: [
      {
        path: 'users',
        component: UsersComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'detail/:id',
        component: UserComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'dashboard',
        component: DashboardComponent,
        data: {
          expectedRole: 'admin'
        }
      },
      {
        path: 'home',
        loadChildren: './views/home/home.module#HomeModule',
        data: {
          preload: true,
          delay: false
        }
      },
      {
        path: 'error',
        component: ErrorComponent
      },
    ]
  },
];
```

Comment: Both your `LoginLayoutComponent` and your `HomeLayoutComponent` have the same path: `''`

Comment: It's because they have child routes. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/46531192/958373 for an example.

Comment: I think @user184994 is right. Even though they have child routes, you need to specify the name of the parent routes.

Comment: @Stephane What's the purpose of having a redirect to inside login? Also what happens if you are not logged in and try to access a non-protected path?

Comment: I solve the issue but cannot explain how.

Comment: @AvinKavish Sorry, I saw your last comment after my resolving the issue.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Found out the culprit! In app.module.ts you need to import AuthModule first. Doing this will allow you to use the path '**' in either 'auth-routing.module.ts' or 'app-routing.module.ts'

```
@NgModule({

  imports: [
    AuthModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    SharedModule
  ],
})
```

---

I was having an infinite loop issue as well. Not sure if this relates to yours but for me I had two routing files. 'app-routing.module.ts' and 'auth-routing.module.ts'. I moved the code below from ' app-routing.module.ts' into 'auth-routing.module.ts' and no more infinite loops! Hope this helps you in some way!

```
 {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: 'my-route',
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`redirectTo` value should always have a leading `/` as it represents the actual route the user should be navigated to.

Change `redirectTo: 'login',` to `redirectTo: '/login',` in your Route Config

Also, this:

```
this.router.navigate(['login']);
```

should be

```
this.router.navigate(['/login']);
```

Comment: I added the slash prefix but it changed nothing on the issue. Again, the issue only occurs when not logged in.

Comment: There is no need for slash prefixes inside `navigate`, that is `navigateByUrl()`

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an exact soution for you, just a few this suggestions for debugging. Try expressing this as:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
  path: '',
  component: LoginLayoutComponent,
  children: [
    {
      path: 'login',
      component: LoginComponent
    },
    {
      path: '',
      component: LoginComponent,
      pathMatch: 'full'
    },
  ]
}
```

to see if it is the route redirect.

Try replacing this with,

```
this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
```

or

```
this.router.navigate(['', 'login']);
```

Answer (score 0):

For my problem, the order of import impacts on this error.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    CommonModule,

    AccountModule, // Load other eager modules first
    AppRoutingModule // Move this AppRouting to the end like this
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case (topic is similar) when I was getting loop it was AuthGuard on Login route.

{
path: 'login',
component: LoginFormComponent,
canActivate: [AuthGuard],
}

To fix this I just removed guard from Login route.