# Multi layout Angular

Tags: angular

I want to make several different module layouts

For example, I made one separate layout and named it user. Now, I have two layouts, one main, root layout and user layout.

In the main layout, I made a button that leads to the user component. And in the user layout, I made a button that leads to the main component.

The task before me is to make it so that when the button is pressed, the component from which I leave disappears. What I mean is that if I'm in the main root component and I press the "user" button which leads to the /user page, then after clicking I should go to the /user page and the main component should disappear. Or if I am in the /user component and press the "home" button that leads to the /home page, then after clicking I should go to the main /home and the /user component should disappear.

I implemented this using a service.

After I did, I noticed that if I go to the /user page and try to refresh it, then at some point, for a fraction of a second, I notice the main component. He appears and disappears. This happens very quickly and at the same time - it is very noticeable. It worries me, I don't know how to get rid of this defect. Please tell me how to get rid of this problem?

**AppComponent**

```
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
    })
    export class AppComponent implements OnDestroy {

      show: boolean = true;

      subscription: Subscription;
      constructor(private showContentService: ShowContentService) {
        this.subscription = showContentService.contentHome.subscribe(value => {
          this.show = value;
        });
      }

      hideContent() {
        this.show = false;
      }


      ngOnDestroy() {
        // Prevent memory leak when component is destroyed
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
      }

    }
```

**app.component.html**

```
    <ng-container *ngIf="show">

      <p>Main page</p>

      <button (click)="hideContent()" routerLink="/user">User</button>

    </ng-container>


    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**AppRoutingModule**

```
    const routes: Routes = [

      { path: 'user', loadChildren: () => import('./user/user.module').then(m => m.UserModule) }

    ];

    @NgModule({
      imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
      exports: [RouterModule]
    })
    export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**ShowContentService**

```
    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class ShowContentService {

      // Observable string sources
      private showContent = new Subject<boolean>();

      // Observable String Streams
      contentHome = this.showContent.asObservable();

      showContentHome(showContent: boolean) {
        this.showContent.next(showContent);
      }

    }
```

**UserComponent**

```
    export class UserComponent {

      constructor(private showContentService: ShowContentService) {
        this.showContentService.showContentHome(false);
      }

      showContentHome() {
        this.showContentService.showContentHome(true);
      }

      ngOnInit(): void {
      }

    }
```

**user.component.html**

```
    <p>User page</p>
    <button (click)="showContentHome()" routerLink="/">Home</button>
```

**UserRoutingModule**

```
    const routes: Routes = [

      { path: '', component: UserComponent }

    ];

    @NgModule({
      imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
      exports: [RouterModule]
    })
    export class UserRoutingModule { }
```

https://github.com/MyTestPerson/Multi-Layout

[image]

Comment: You should be using routes to navigate, not a custom service.

Comment: @Chris Hamilton I am using routes. Or not noticeable?

Comment: Yes, but you're only using it for the user component - not this other component that's giving you issues. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46527826/best-method-to-set-different-layout-for-different-pages-in-angular-4. The reason you see the flash is because you have `show` default to true, you could default this to false instead, but that link will show you the proper way to implement layouts for different routes. You can have a separate route for each layout.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best method to set different layout for different pages in angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46527826/best-method-to-set-different-layout-for-different-pages-in-angular-4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution is to use multiple `<router-outlet>` elements.  You can have a router outlet for each module.

The way I would structure it is to have your main `app` be just a router-outlet element in the template.  I would then create two separate modules, one for `main`, and one for `user`.  Each of these modules would contain their own router outlet and their own layout components which would render in the root apps router outlet.

#### app-routing.module.ts

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => import('./main/main.module').then((m) => m.MainModule),
  },
  {
    path: 'user',
    loadChildren: () => import('./user/user.module').then((m) => m.UserModule),
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

#### app.component.html

```html
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

#### main-routing.module.ts

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { MainLayoutComponent } from './containers/main-layout/main-layout.component';
import { MainPageComponent } from './pages/main-page/main-page.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    // This layout component will render in app's router-outlet
    component: MainLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        // This page component will render in mains router-outlet
        component: MainPageComponent,
      },
    ],
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class MainRoutingModule {}
```

#### main-layout.component.html

```html
<h1>Main Layout</h1>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

#### user-routing.module.ts

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    // This layout component will render in apps router-outlet
    component: UserLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        // This child component will render in users router-outlet
        component: UserPageComponent,
      },
    ],
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class UserRoutingModule {}
```

#### user-layout.component.html

```js
<h1>User Layout</h1>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

I mocked up a stackblitz that demonstrates the solution.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-oy44ja

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was trying to do.