# Angular 2 - routing to a new page

Tags: angular2-routing

I have a main page with two buttons and routing works fine. However, these two components are presented on this main page with buttons, because of `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Main page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
     <h1>My Page</h1>
     <button class="button_blue"><a routerLink="/pageB">1</a></button>
     <button class="button_red"><a routerLink="/pageC">2</a></button>
     <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I click on a main page button, how can I open my *'pageB'*  as complete new empty page, without any links or buttons? `target="_blank"` gives me the same, just on an another tab.

Comment: I don't understand, how can you click on a button on a page with no buttons? I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: @Train Well, english is not my strong side .. I edited the question to be more clear.

Comment: when you say new page, do you mean the default page for the browser when you open it? Or a white empty page?

Comment: Main page has two buttons. Clicking one button should open a new empty page with its component, without buttons and links from a main page. And all that via routerLink not href.

Comment: To render only `pageB` without the main page, you need to create another layout. Is this what you asking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40508557/multiple-layout-for-different-pages-in-angular-2 Maybe you can show us some example screenshots of the output.

Comment: Yes, this is what I would like to do. Thank you for the link, child route will help