# Angular Multiple layouts routing is not working

Tags: html, angular, typescript, routes, angular-routing

I have the follwing multi-layout structure without lazy loading. When navigating to
https://localhost:44327/admin or /student it doesn't show anything. If I use an empty path instead of admin and student then navigate to it's child (/manageConcern) route it loads the first (AdminLayoutComponent) Layout specified in routing. The second LayoutCompnent (/trainings) doesn't load. looks like the router-outlet in app.component can't read the paths. Any idea what I am missing here? This is what I want to achieve https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-multi-layout-example

**Routing-module.ts**

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
  {
    path: 'admin',
    component: AdminLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      {path: '', redirectTo: 'manageConcern', pathMatch: 'full'},
      {path: 'manageConcern', component: MasterConcernComponent},
      {path: 'createTraining', component: AdminComponent},
    ]
  },
  {
    path: 'student',
    component: StudentLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      {path: '', redirectTo: 'trainings', pathMatch: 'full'},
      {path: 'trainings', component: TrainingsComponent},
    ]
  }
]),
```

**AdminLayoutComponent.html**

```
<app-header></app-header>
    <app-menu [menuItems]="menuItems"></app-menu>
    <div class="app-body-content m-5 p-4">
       <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
```

**StudentLayoutComponent.html**

```
    <app-menu [menuItems]="menuItems"></app-menu>
    <div class="app-body-content m-5 p-4">
       <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
```

**app.component.html**

```
 <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: I want a simple multi-layout structure without using lazy loading. Check this example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-multi-layout-example @JasonWhite

Comment: at first look, your code seems alright. is there any error throwing? if you could replicate your error with stackblitz i can take a look into this.

Comment: @RameezRami I don't get any error that is the problem. I used your example and set layout routes as empty paths and commented the redirectPath of the second layout (training). When the two layout paths are empty it navigate to the first layout in the routing list and it is rendered. My router just isn't be able to read the paths if it's specified. It's almost 2 days am struggling with this.

Comment: @RameezRami I GOT IT, I just needed to add <base href="/"> in my index.html because the active route for app.component.ts was unkown. it's really strange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As app.component.ts is not a routed component it doesn't know anything about the active route. If you want to use your main router-outlet in app.component.ts then you have to add  `<base href="/">`  in your index.html.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to add main route to routes array.
{
path: '',
component: AnyComponent,
}

Comment: Check this example, I have the same structure  stackblitz.com/edit/angular-multi-layout-example